# How to find average of an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, average

I am trying to find the averages of several hashes in an array that look like this:

```
[{"path"=>"/abcd.com", "time"=>0.503},
 {"path"=>"/abcd.com", "time"=>0.765},
 {"path"=>"/abcd.com", "time"=>0.553}]
```

The arrays are grouped by the path, and I want to find the average time it takes for this path to load.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 averages = grouped_data.each do |array|
   array.each do |hash|
     hash["time"].reduce(:+) \ hash.length
   end 
 end
```

It's not working I think because the times in the hashes are floats. So I tried a work around by adding a total and without using `reduce`, but the `total` returned `0`:

```
 averages = grouped_data.each do |array|
   total = 0
   array.each do |hash|
     hash["time"] += total \ hash.length
   end 
   return total
 end
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: (1) What is the backslash doing there? `total \ hash.length`. (2) Your hashes consist of only a single entry. Hence, `hash.length` will alwas be 1.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
array = [{"path"=>"/sale.html", "time"=>0.503}, {"path"=>"/sale.html", "time"=>0.765}, {"path"=>"/sale.html", "time"=>0.553}]
average = array.map { |x| x["time"] }.sum / array.size # 0.6070
```

You can also use `sum` directly on array:

```
average = array.sum { |x| x["time"] } / array.size # 0.6070
```

Comment: Use sum with block: `array.sum { |x| x["time"] }`

Comment: It says undefined method sum for float for the first one and undefined method sum for Array for the second

Comment: @ShannonNolan Are you trying this with different array of hashes ? I have tested this for the above mentioned array and I have got result.

Comment: @ShannonNolan what ruby version do you use?

Comment: @ShannonNolan `Enumberable#sum` was added to ruby version `2.4.0`. (The method has also been available in `ActiveSupport` (i.e. typically within rails projects) for many years.) Unless you have a good reason not to, I'd advise simply updating your ruby version to the current latest: `2.5.1`

Answer (score 1):

Made an assumption about your `grouped_data` structure, please verify.

```
grouped_data = [
                [
                 {"path"=>"/sale.html", "time"=>0.503},
                 {"path"=>"/sale.html", "time"=>0.765},
                 {"path"=>"/sale.html", "time"=>0.553}
                ],
                [
                 {"path"=>"/sales.html", "time"=>1.0},
                 {"path"=>"/sales.html", "time"=>1.0},
                 {"path"=>"/sales.html", "time"=>4.0}
                ]
               ]
```

If you want the averages per path:

```
averages = grouped_data.map do |array|
 array.inject(0) do |sum, hash|
   sum + hash["time"]
   end.fdiv(array.size) 
end

 #=> [0.6070000000000001, 2.0]
```

Or hashes with the path and average times:

```
avs = grouped_data.map { |array|
  array.inject({}) { |sum, hash|
    sum.merge(hash) { |k, o, n| k == 'time' ? o + n : o }
  }.map { |k, v| [k, k == 'time' ? v.fdiv(array.size) : v] }.to_h
}

 #=> [{ "path" => "/sale.html",  "time" => 0.6070000000000001 },
 #    { "path" => "/sales.html", "time" => 2.0 }]
```

Comment: If this works for you, I'll add a little explanation if needed.

Comment: did you try ? gives error.. please publish complete runnable code

Comment: @peter I've inferred `grouped_data` is an array of arrays each of which is filled with hashes. I'm just waiting for confirmation from the OP. I may be completely wrong.